# Trying to solve for b as a function of i, but facing some problem

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functional-style, code-review

```
k = 10^12;(*1*10^b;*)
a = 1/(4*b^3*(1 - Cosh[b]*Cos[b]));
a1 = (Cos[b*x] - Cosh[b*x]);
a2 = (Sin[b*x] - Sinh[b*x]);
phi1 = (Cos[b] - Cosh[b])*(Sin[b*(1 - i)] - Sinh[b*(1 - i)]);
phi2 = (Sin[b] - Sinh[b])*(Cos[b*(1 - i)] - Cosh[b*(1 - i)]);
phi3 = (Sin[b] + Sinh[b])*(Sin[b*(1 - i)] - Sinh[b*(1 - i)]);
phi4 = (Cos[b] - Cosh[b])*(Cos[b*(1 - i)] - Cosh[b*(1 - i)]);
eq = a ((phi1 - phi2)*(a1 /. x -> i) + (phi3 + phi4)*(a2 /. x -> i));
eq1 = 1 + (k*eq);
i0 = Values@NSolve[(eq1 /. i -> .1) && 0 < b < 20, b][[All, 1]]
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[eq1 /. b -> b[i], i], b[.1] == i0}, 
   b, {i, $MachineEpsilon, .5}, PrecisionGoal -> 16];
Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, .5}]
```

What I am trying here is find the first few initial guess of roots, and using this initial roots to find the first few roots for different values i of from   0.01 to  0.5 using NDSolve

Comment: Did you look at the error message? You should use `NSolve[(eq1 == 0 /. i->.1) ...]`. However, the expression is getting too complicated for NSolve, so I suggest using a FindRoot based method to get the initial set of roots.

Comment: Sir, you only suggested me to use this. I find it very easy and it actually solves my problem in the single shot. I rather prefer this method. would you please guide me how to tackle it.

Comment: Your `eq1` is probably too difficult for NSolve. So use FindRoot instead to get the initial values `i0`. Once you have `i0` you can still use NDSolveValue to get the parametric dependence on `i`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and update once I get solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're equation is getting complicated enough that [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve) will not be able to arrive at a solution in a reasonable amount of time. So, I suggest using a [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) method to get the initial roots. For example, here is a plot of `eq1` vs `b` for `i=.1`:

```
Plot[eq1 /. i->.1, {b, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Eyeballing the graph, I would use the following [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot):

```
i0 = b /. FindRoot[eq1/.i->1/10, {b, {5,8,12,16,18}}, WorkingPrecision->30]
```

> {5.12956120101788934566197713658, 8.53225106274681114613649481380, \
>   11.9649691149199775449189438409, 15.4038236411023191375435466893, \
>   18.8473632309297465111047259808}

I used a higher working precision because the ODE needs higher precision to get a good result. Now, the next step is to solve the ODE, but for some reason, Mathematica's default equation processing code needs some help. Here is an [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) call that seems to work:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {
    b'[i] == (-D[eq1,i]/D[eq1,b] /. b->b[i]),
    b[1/10] == i0
    },
    b,
    {i, $MachineEpsilon, .5},
    PrecisionGoal->30
];

Plot[sol[x],{x,0,.5}]
```

> (some messages)

[image]

Comment: I am also getting the same roots from find root command. I now just solve  using NDslove. Thanks a lot. It is very helpful.